# Convergence in Probability,Expected Value, uniform continous function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

$X_n, X $ are random variables in a probability space $ (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.

**Show:** If $ X_n \rightarrow X $  converges in probability, than  $$E(f(X_n)) \rightarrow E(f(X)) $$ for every uniform continous and bounded function f.

The convergence in probability means: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0 $

Because f is bounded $M:= sup_{x \in \Omega} f(x)<\infty$

Be $\epsilon>0$ , because f is uniform continuous we find a $\delta>0: \forall x,y: |x-y|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon $

I already come to the equation:
$|E(f(X_n))-E(f(X))|\le  E(|f(X_n)-f(X)|) = E(|f(X_n)-f(X)|*\chi_{|X_n-X|\le \delta}+|f(X_n)-f(X)|*\chi_{|X_n-X|> \delta})\le \epsilon E(\chi_{|X_n-X|\le \delta})+2M*E(\chi_{|X_n-X|> \delta}) =\epsilon (1- P(|(X_n-X| > \delta)) + 2M* P(|X_n-X|>\delta) $

So  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |E(f(X_n))-E(f(X))| \le \epsilon$

Because $\epsilon>0$ the statement follows.

Comment: You have some mistakes: (i) The sentence "Be $\epsilon>0$ and pick $\delta>0$ s.t. $f$ is uniformly continuous" does not make sense.  Note that $f$ is given to be uniformly continuous (regardless of $\epsilon,\delta$).  Can you give a correct defintion of unif continuous?  (ii) Note that $M$ is a given bound and is known before any $\epsilon$ or $\delta$ is chosen, (iii) Your inequalities accidentally write "$x_n$" instead of "$X_n$." (iv) You might want to decouple the "$\delta$"s used in your "convergence in prob" and "unif continuous."  It is easier to just use limit def of "conv in prob."

Comment: You might also simplify your last inequality to write $\leq \epsilon + 2MP[|X_n-X|>\delta]$.

Comment: Your edits look good:  You are essentially done, can you finish?

Comment: Looks good:  A _very_ minor point that is not necessary:  When taking limits of both sides of $$|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq \epsilon + 2MP[|X_n-X|>\delta]$$ , strictly speaking you should take a $\limsup$ since you do not know if the left-hand-side has a well defined limit yet.  That would give $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]| \leq \epsilon$ and since this holds _for all_ $\epsilon>0$ you conclude the limit exists and is 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help, is it right that $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, but $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  If you like you can view $H(\omega) = f(X(\omega))$ and so $H:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. In that case, $H$ is a random variable. You could also write $H=f(X)$ (so $f(X)$ is a random variable).